# Как выбрать записи из связанных таблиц HQL ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Есть 3 таблицы product, category, product_and_category. Связь для category:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "product_and_category",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
private Collection<Prouct> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

Связь для product

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "product_and_category",joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
private Collection<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
```

Подскажите как написать **HQL** запрос чтобы например получить список category которые относятся к product с id = 1

Comment: `Collection<Prouct>`...это опечатка или у Вас так в коде и называется? я про `Prouct` (БЕЗ `d`)

Comment: хотя в таблицах у вас уже нормально указано...в общем будьте аккуратнее

Comment: в ответе я везде писал `Product`...поэтому если вдруг будут расхождения, то примените поправки либо на мой код, либо на ваш...тут неоднозначная ситуация

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто нужно делаете `JOIN`

В HQL это будет выглядеть так:

```
"SELECT c FROM Category c JOIN c.products p WHERE p.id = :idProduct"
```

Ну и пример кода с `Query`

```
TypedQuery<Category> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Category c JOIN c.products p WHERE p.id = :idProduct", Category.class);
query.setParameter("idProduct", product.getId());
List<Category> categories = query.getResultList();
```